# How to getting image file URL from a folder inside web project?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

How to getting image file URL in myjava(Test.java implements spring controller) file from a folder inside web project?

MYProject/WebContent/images/isilogo.gif.

I want to take isilog.gif from MYProject/WebContent/images/isilogo.gif for Bar code label print header of PDF . 
public static final String IMG = "D://MY WORK PLACE/MYProject/WebContent/images/jsw.gif"; 
Image img = Image.getInstance(IMG);
Now its takes static from my work place.I wants it's take from myproject  WebContent dynamically . Please help me any one friends. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: What error message do you get when you try?

Comment: @Juan &Joshua, I want to take isilog.gif from MYProject/WebContent/images/isilogo.gif for Bar code label print header of PDF .  public static final String IMG = "D://MY WORK PLACE/MYProject/WebContent/images/jsw.gif"; Image img = Image.getInstance(IMG); now   its takes static from my work place. now i wants it's take from myproject dynamicaly  . Please if know help me.. Thanks in advance..